# Google Charts Line graph displaying only first and last label

Tags: google-visualization

I have a line graph and the X-axis comprises of dates. what I want to do is that, my chart should display only the first-date and the last-date on the axis with sufficient gap in between to display the data related to the other dates (but NOT the label)
eg- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujSRu.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `hAxis.ticks` option:

```
hAxis: {
    // set the x-axis to show dates at each end, Oct 27 2013 - Nov 18 2013
    // with no tick marks or labels in between
    ticks: [new Date(2013, 9, 27), new Date(2013, 10, 18)]
}
```

Comment: Could you show me in this case -> https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart how I can manipulate to display only 'A' and 'N'

Comment: It doesn't work with discrete ("string" type) axes.  You can use the `hAxis.ticks` option to put custom labels on numeric values, however, if that is what you need.  In the playground example, if you change the letters to numbers 0-13 (eg: `['A', 1, 1, 0.5],` => `[0, 1, 1, 0.5],`), then you can set the `hAxis.ticks` option to `[{v: 0, f: 'A'}, {v: 13, f: 'N'}]` to get an axis that starts at 'A' and ends at 'N' with no values listed in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact amount of data entries, you may do:

```
hAxis: {showTextEvery: 4}
```